# Solve $\begin{cases} y<x\\ -(x-y)^2\leq 4 (1-y-x+xy) \end{cases} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system
$$\begin{cases}
y<x\\
-(x-y)^2\leq 4 (1-y-x+xy)
\end{cases}
$$
I tried to solve it graphically (e.g. $y=x$ is the bisector) but I can't handle the second inequality.

Maybe I should solve the second inequality algebraically in $y$ or $x$ and then set $y<x$.

Suggestions?

Comment: Looking at it numerically, it seems like the second equation is always true (!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

You can rewrite the inequality as
$$(x-y)^2+4xy -4(x+y)+4\ge 0\iff (x+y)^2 -4(x+y)+4\ge 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that the second inequality is always satisfied:
$$-t^2+2ts-s^2=-(t-s)^2=−(x−y)^2\leq4(1−y−x+xy)=4ts\Leftrightarrow (t+s)^2\geq 0$$
where $t=x-1$ and $s=y-1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint*** the second inequality is equivalent to $(x+y-2)^2>0$, so effectively it can be ignored in this case...